# Margin/padding at top of list-element with textarea inside in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm having an odd top padding/margin in Firefox.

Given this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><textarea>item 1</textarea></li>
    <li><textarea>item 2</textarea></li>
    <li><textarea>item 3</textarea></li>
    <li><textarea>item 4</textarea></li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS:

```
ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:300px;
}

ul li
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:17px;
}

ul li textarea
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size:11px;
    height:15px;
}
```

When the list renders, the first element is displayed with a small extra top-margin causing the textareas inside to overflow the list as seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/asgerhallas/2fwJZ/

I do not have this issue in Chrome. Does anyone has an explanation and a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display: block` to `ul li textarea`:

http://jsfiddle.net/2fwJZ/1/

Or, add `vertical-align: top`:

http://jsfiddle.net/2fwJZ/2/

---

The problem in this case is that Firefox defaults to `vertical-align: text-bottom` for `textarea` elements, whereas Chrome defaults to `vertical-align: baseline`.

Comment: This also worked for removing unexpected & unwanted whitespace _below_ a `textarea` within a `li` in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

you can all so add `line-height:1;` if you gust want a different 
approach